# Haven't got or haven't gotten?

Tags: have-got, got-gotten

Which is correct?

- I haven't gotten any sleep since Monday
- I haven't got any sleep since Monday

(Are both of these sentences wrong? Should I use "I haven't slept since Monday" instead?)

Thank you x

Comment: Answered at _Difference between “I have got” and “I have gotten”_.

Comment: It depends on what you want to say. If you want to say about you not **getting** sleep or if you haven't **slept**.

Comment: British idioms, in order of my own preference would be 1. *I haven't slept since Monday*. 2. *I haven't had any sleep since Monday*.  Sometimes people will say *I can't get any sleep...(with all the noise from downstairs).*. It would be unusual to hear the past tense "got" in this context. As a very general rule "get, got and gotten" tend to be American, the last one exclusively American.

Answer (score 9):

An American might say *I have not gotten any sleep since Monday*

A British person would not say that. They MIGHT say *I have not got any sleep since Monday* but, in my view, it is not really idiomatic in any UK register. Others may disagree.

I might say either *I have not had any sleep since Monday*, or *I have not slept since Monday*.

The past participle ***gotten*** is to all intents obsolete in British idiomacy.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "haven't had any sleep".  I would also agree about the second sentence being non-idiomatic for British English.

Answer (score 4):

> Are both of these sentences wrong? Should I use "I haven't slept since Monday" instead?)

It is really your choice, it mostly depends on what you want to say. Although I doubt it would make a huge difference if you used the second one. 
**If you want to say about you not getting sleep or if you haven't slept.**

---

Also remember that: **gotten** is the standard past participle for American English. While **got** is the past participle used commonly in British English.

I am new here so my answers may not be ***perfect***.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely say "I haven't slept since Monday" to avoid the "got-gotten" problem. The other two expressions are not wrong, but readers may have different opinions on the usage, depending on what they are used to (their backgrounds).

If you are interested, here are two articles on this "Got vs. Gotten" topic for you:
http://grammarist.com/usage/got-gotten/
http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gotten.html

Enjoy reading!